# How to insert row a in one column (PK) table?

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a table with one and only one column, which is an identity column (PK) of this table. How to insert row in this table?

```
INSERT INTO table_name
```

doesn't work, neither does:

```
INSERT INTO table_name() VALUES()
```

---

**VALID SOLUTION FROM THE ANSWER:**

```
INSERT INTO table_name DEFAULT VALUES
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY 
)

INSERT INTO @TABLE DEFAULT VALUES

SELECT * FROM @TABLE
```

Answer (score 1):

You should enable identity insert on the table, so that you can insert values into the column.

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT table_name ON
```